# Animação durante requisição ajax

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

Pessoal eu tenho uma requisição ajax, Só que ela está demorando um pouquinho, ela só me da o retorno quando for com sucesso ou não, mas durante a requisição eu não mostro ao usuário como está o procedimento. Como eu faço para que, enquanto a requisição é feita, eu mostre uma animaçãozinha mostrando que a requisição está sendo processada?
Meu servidor de testes: http://tiagotestes.esy.es
PS: as imagens não me pertencem apenas usei para fins de testes.
Form:

```
    <div class="col-md-6" >
       <form id="formcontato">
          <br>
          <label> Nome:</label>
          <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <p class="palerta" id="valida_nome"></p>
          <br>
          <label>Email: </label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <p class="palerta" id="valida_email"></p>
          <br>
          <label>Telefone:</label>
          <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="00 0000-0000" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <p class="palerta" id="valida_telefone"></p>
          <br />
          <label>Mensagem:</label>
          <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Deixe sua mensagem" name="mensagem" id="mensagem"></textarea>
          <p class="palerta" id="valida_mensagem"></p>
          <br>
          <div class="text-center">
             <input type="submit" class="button" value="Enviar"id="enviar"/>
          </div>
       </form>
       <div class="notificacao text-center" id="notificacao">
          <h2 id="titnotif">
          </h2>
          <p id="txtnotif"></p>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Request:

```
 $("#formcontato").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         if (validar()){
           $.ajax({
               url: "https://formspree.io/tiago_tmax@hotmail.com",
               method: "POST",
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(){
                   $("#titnotif").html("Seu formulário foi enviado com sucesso!");
                   $("#txtnotif").html("Logo farei contato :)");
                   $("#notificacao").addClass("boa");
                   $("#notificacao").fadeIn("slow");
                   $("input").val("");
                   $("textarea").val("");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#notificacao").fadeOut("slow");
                }, 5000);
               },
               error: function(){
                   $("#titnotif").html("Sua mensagem não foi enviada!");
                   $("#txtnotif").html("Por favor, tente contato pelo meu E-mail, ou telefone.");
                   $("#notificacao").addClass("ruim");
                   $("#notificacao").fadeIn("slow");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#notificacao").fadeOut("slow");
                }, 5000);
               }
           });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes do Success adicione um beforeSend, assim:

```
$("#formcontato").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     if (validar()){
       $.ajax({
           url: "https://formspree.io/tiago_tmax@hotmail.com",
           method: "POST",
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           dataType: "json",
           beforeSend: function(){
               #('#titnotif').html('<img src="imagemLoading">');
           },
           success: function(){
               $("#titnotif").html("Seu formulário foi enviado com sucesso!");
               $("#txtnotif").html("Logo farei contato :)");
               $("#notificacao").addClass("boa");
               $("#notificacao").fadeIn("slow");
               $("input").val("");
               $("textarea").val("");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#notificacao").fadeOut("slow");
            }, 5000);
           },
           error: function(){
               $("#titnotif").html("Sua mensagem não foi enviada!");
               $("#txtnotif").html("Por favor, tente contato pelo meu E-mail, ou telefone.");
               $("#notificacao").addClass("ruim");
               $("#notificacao").fadeIn("slow");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#notificacao").fadeOut("slow");
            }, 5000);
           }
       });
    }
});
```

Voce pode trocar o alert por qualquer coisa, um load ou o que preferir